# C# extending existing Method of the ILog Interface of Log4net

Tags: c#, inheritance, log4net

I am currently trying to extend the behaviour of the Ilog.Error Method

I would normally just inherit from a class, overwrite the Method I want to extend and use my new class instead, like so:

```
public class MyLogger:Logger
{
    overwrite Error(..)
    {
        base.Error(..);
        Mycode(..);
    }
}
```

However, since I am dealing with interfaces when generating Loggers via Logmanager, there is no class I could extend in this fashion. Is there another way to extend Methods that also works with interfaces?

Comment: I think you can use [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: Please try to use extension methods not to override the main error method you can extend the Ilogger interface with whatever behavior you want to extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overwrite` is not a keyword in `C#`. Use `override` In order for this method to be overriden from the base class, in needs to be marked either `virtual`, which means that it can be overriden or `abstract` which means that it **has** to be overriden. For further references see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance#abstract-and-virtual-methods

EDIT:

As some of the comments states that you should create an extension method, you can to it like this:

```
public static class Log4NetExtension 
{    
   public static void LogError(this Logger logger) 
   {
     logger.Error(..);
     //your code
   }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var logger = new Logger();
logger.LogError();
```

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the direction of extension methods, that is what i was looking for.